# Xamarin ios: having trouble with OpenSans-Light

Tags: ios, xamarin, fonts, visual-studio-mac

Weirdly I can create the font correctly, but the uiFont is null on the first file below, I get a font and a uiFont for the second file. Both files are in a folder called Resources with a Build Action of BundleResources. Any idea why this is happening?

Fonts were downloaded from here: https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache/opensans

This doesn't work:

```
        var data = NSData.FromFile("OpenSans-Light.ttf");
        var provider = new CGDataProvider(data);
        var font = CGFont.CreateFromProvider(provider);
        var uiFont = UIFont.FromName(font.PostScriptName, 44f);
```

This works:

```
        var data = NSData.FromFile("OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        var provider = new CGDataProvider(data);
        var font = CGFont.CreateFromProvider(provider);
        var uiFont = UIFont.FromName(font.PostScriptName, 44f);
```

Comment: none of what you're doing appears to follow the docs on using a custom font in iOS: https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/

Comment: What is the `font.PostScriptName`? It should be either "Open Sans Light" or "OpenSans-Light"

Comment: OpenSans-Light... this all is the "long" way of doing it to see if I could even load in the font from a file... but I'm thinking I actually didn't add it to the info.plist... the others I added several days earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I didn't add the light font to the info.plist